# Class from rt.jar not found

Tags: jboss7.x, java, classnotfoundexception

In JBOSS EAP 6 (AS 7):

I am making a call to Spring's WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndRecieve
which in turn is having trouble finding a class that exisits in rt.jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl
```

I do not understand how this can happen? Surely everything that is in rt.jar gets loaded up on startup?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Kenny

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok I found a solution (not sure if its the correct way, but it works).

I noticed by running java -verbose:class that only some of the classes in rt.jar were loaded and not the one I needed (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl)

So in JBoss EAP 6 (As 7) there is a modules directory ($JBOSS_HOME/modules/)
And under here there is sun/jdk/main/modules.xml

I added the following entries:

```
<path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom"/>
<path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni"/>
<path name="com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp"/>
```

(last 2 becuase of subsequent class not found exceptions after adding in dom)

As I said I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct way to do this.
Any input is welcome!

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: This is somewhat of the solution you need. Other would be to include it in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. 
In any case you should not use com.sun* packages inside your application, as that makes it non portable to other jvms and it packages could be removed without notice.

Comment: Hi ctmoc, Thanks for the reply. I am using Spring's webservicetemplate which is using the com.sun* package. Are you saying I should not be using this? Thanks.

Comment: Wow thanks. I was having issue with `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` on Wildfly 9.0.1, this is now solved.

Comment: Had the same issue while using Liferay and SAAJ, thanks a bunch @km2000

Comment: JDK class whitelisting in WildFly is a feature - init?